# Sending message to Kafka on dynamically created topic gives error LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to send the message on dynamically created topic using below code:

```
@Service
public class KafkaMessageSender {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMessageSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String topic, String payload) {
        String topicName =  topic + Integer.valueOf(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(1, 4))%100;
        kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, payload);
        LOGGER.info("sent payload to topic='{}'", topicName);
    }
}
```

When I call this send method with topic = 'somethingnew', I get below error, (its interesting that its able to send some message, but for many it gives the error, and after some time, it starts sending the message on those topic too) but when I restart the server, and call the send method again with topic = 'somethingnew', it works fine! Is there some potential bug in kafka? I am using spring boot version: 1.5.4.RELEASE.

```
2018-02-13 09:52:35.927  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 0.10.1.1
2018-02-13 09:52:35.927  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247
2018-02-13 09:52:36.067  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.5=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:36.272  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.5'
2018-02-13 09:52:36.372  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.93=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:36.475  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.93'
2018-02-13 09:52:36.583  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.4=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:36.686  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.4'
2018-02-13 09:52:36.794  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.7=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:36.897  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.7'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.008  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 12 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.0=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:37.110  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.0'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.220  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 15 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:37.320  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.1'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.431  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 18 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.10=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:37.534  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.10'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.534  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.4'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.642  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 22 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.71=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:37.747  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.71'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.859  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 25 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.2=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:37.962  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.2'
2018-02-13 09:52:37.963  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.7'
2018-02-13 09:52:38.074  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 29 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.33=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2018-02-13 09:52:38.176  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.33'
2018-02-13 09:52:38.176  INFO [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [      Thread-28] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncDataTopicNew123.1'
2018-02-13 09:52:38.285  WARN [betsync-adapter-service,,,] 22241 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 33 : {betsyncDataTopicNew123.17=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

And this is just the warning, and we are not getting any exception, so have no idea if the message gets lost or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `AdminClient` to create topics on-demand.

Spring for Apache Kafka provides a convenient `KafkaAdmin` which can create topics for `NewTopic` beans in the application context, but it can also be used to create an `AdminClient` so you can manually create topics - [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_configuring_topics). Spring Boot 2.0 auto configuration registers one for you.

Once you have an `AdminClient` instance, use one of the `createTopics()` methods. See the `AdminClient` javadocs for more information. Be sure to wait for the `CreateTopicsResult`'s `Future<?>`s to complete.

Comment: You either need to create the topic using the `kafka-topics.sh` command line tool, or add a `NewTopic` bean to your configuration. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#configuring-topics

Answer (score 2):

The error `Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 ... LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` is because the [topic doesn't exist](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3334) at the time of publication of the first message, and will be autocreated if your configuration allows for auto creation of topics.

The message above refers to the fact that Kafka is unable to obtain metadata about the topic, its partitions, and consumer groups (e.g. unable to find the offset per partition per consumer group).

As you've observed, the second and subsequent messages send to the topic do not raise this error.

It is fairly unusual to create topics with random names as you appear to be doing, since consumers would need to 'find' the topic in order to consume from it. The general idea is to pre-create Kafka topics before using them, which will allow you to configure important factors such as partitioning etc.

Comment: Hi @StuartLC, I have a requirement to create topic dynamically for each feedId and using topicPattern on listener side, I am able to listen the dynamically created topic too. The main reason for this is that out of multiple listeners, one listener will receive all messages of one feed, so we will able to load balance and make the processing mutually exclusive.

Comment: What I haven't able to test so far is, whether I have lost the previous message or not. I am testing it right now.